# RX to manage and join n child processes

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

I'm using RX to merge parallel processes, which are themselves managed by RX (over a MassTransit workflow).

The task is to kick off multiple processes, and once they have all returned, then move on.

So for 4 processes I  currently have the following which works perfectly :

```
IObservable<ExportServiceResult> one = ExecuteExport(campaignId, "Export1");
IObservable<ExportServiceResult> two = ExecuteExport(campaignId, "Export2");
IObservable<ExportServiceResult> three = ExecuteExport(campaignId, "Export3");
IObservable<ExportServiceResult> four = ExecuteExport(campaignId, "Export4");

// we need all exports to complete before we can move to the next step
var allExportsForCampaign = one
    .And(two)
    .And(three)
    .And(four)
    .Then((first, second, third, fourth) =>
    {
         var result = new ExportBatchResult();

         result.ExportResults.Add(first);
         result.ExportResults.Add(second);
         result.ExportResults.Add(third);
         result.ExportResults.Add(fourth);
         return result;
    }
);

return Observable.When(allExportsForCampaign);
```

In this above, ExecuteExport(2) returns one value and completes.

Ideally we want to be able to configure this system to be given *n* exports in configuration, and that handled dynamically.

My question is : it this possible to wait for *n* observables to return a value, then move on with the values accessible in some form of collection?

Or am I going about this the wrong way and there another way to approach this using RX?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Honestly this sounds like something more suited for the TPL, simply because these exports are only returning one result, and because you want to wait for a number of exports to be completed before moving on.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine the observables with Merge(), and then aggregate the resulting observable.

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<ExportServiceResult>> observers;
IEnumerable<ExportServiceResult> result = new List<ExportServiceResult>();

var o = observers.Aggregate( (x,y) => x.Merge(y))
    .Aggregate( result, (l,x) => l.Concat( new[]{ x }));
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly cleaner way is this:

```
IEnumerable<IObservable<TResult>> obs;
IList<TResult> result = Observable.Zip(obs).Wait();
```

If you don't want it to block, just leave out the `Wait()` to have an `IObservable<IList<TResult>>` you can Subscribe to or compose with more Rx.